# Hiding specific rows in a table until an Ajax request completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a specific rows in a HTML table that I do not want to be displayed when the page loads. 
There will be an Ajax request made after the page loads that returns values that would populate the table rows.
So I would want to display these rows only after the Ajax returns with a response and until then I want to display a 'loading' message in place of these rows.
I tried adding these rows in a div and used jquery's show()/hide() appropriately but that didn't work.
I'm new to JS and jQuery, so any help is appreciated.

```
    <html>
    <body onload="my_ajax_func()">
    <table>
    .
    . <!-- Other rows that will be displayed-->
    .
    <tr>
        <th colspan=2 class="custHeader">High Value Flags</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align=right><div id="loading_msg"><b>Loading..</b></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="val_header" class=caption>Value Tier:&nbsp;</td><td id="val"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="hypo_val_header" class=caption>Hypo Value Tier:&nbsp;</td><td id="hypo_val"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="service_type_header" class=caption>Service Type:&nbsp;</td><td id="service_type"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>

<script>
function my_ajax_func() {
    //retrieves values for table rows
    //on success calls another func, say display_data
}
function display_data() {
    $("loading_msg").hide();
document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = <some_value>;
document.getElementById("hypo_val").innerHTML = <some_value>;
document.getElementById("service_type").innerHTML = <some_value>;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Basically, I want a div for 'loading' message which would be displayed by default. Once Ajax request completes successfully, that div must be hidden and another div (with these 2 table rows) must be displayed in it's place.

Comment: Please provide your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide your rows at page loading, just create two css classes like this:

```
.displayNone{
    display:none;
}

.displayBlock{
    display:block;
}
```

and use this class in your rows

```
<tr class="displayNone"></tr>
```

So when page loads, this rows will be hidden.

So, in ajax success put this js:

```
$(".displayNone").removeClass("displayNone").addClass("displayHidden");
```

Then, download some loading gif image like this:

```
http://thinkfuture.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/loading_spinner.gif
```

After that, wrap this img tag in a div with "displayNone" class too, and use inverse way of your rows:

Before your ajax call, remove "displayNone" class from it, and put "displayBlock".

Finally, in ajax success, remove "displayBlock" class from div, and put back "displayNone" to hide it again.

Hope it help.

Some doubts, please let me know.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You Can use .done() method

```
$.post( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "ajax request completed" );
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to change text values in the rows, you might be able to get away with a class value of "display: none" in CSS for each complete row, until you are ready to update it. But you are going to have to have some unique ID for each, or way of counting children, in order to find that row again when you need to update it. Also, your table needs to be valid without those rows.

The other way to handle this would be to just add new rows dynamically. If you do this, remember the rows do not exist in DOM until you insert them there, and so you can't reference them before.

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned above ajax has some methods like before and done where you have opportunity to show and hide your elements.

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr><th>header 1</th><th>header2</th><th>header3</th><tr>
    <tr id="loadingrow"><th colspan=3>Loading Data...</th><tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>....
$.ajax({
url: "http://fdafdas",
beforeSend: function(  ) {
  $('#loadingrow').show();
}
})
.done(function( data ) {
$('#loadingrow').hide();

 //load your data
}
});
```